# How to install/deploy a sources jar with maven ant tasks

Tags: maven, ant, maven-ant-tasks

I had a hard time understanding how to install or deploy a jar file with its accompanying sources (or any additional classifier for that matter). The [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/reference.html) wasn't clear to me and left me to do some trial and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to use a classifier with maven ant run tasks:

```
<target name="install-jar">
    ...
    <artifact:pom id="sharedPom" file="shared/pom.xml" />
    <artifact:install file="${classesdir}/shared.jar" >
        <pom refid="sharedPom" />
        <attach file="${builddir}/shared-sources.jar" classifier="sources" />
    </artifact:install>
</target>
```

The attach referenced to in the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/reference.html) is meant to be a sub-element. Hope this helps.